# Apple Developer account - how can I automatically switch team?

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-developer

Is there a way to automatically (i.e. programatically, via a specified URL, or by some other means) switch team after logging into the Apple Developer portal, but *without using Fastlane*? I have the following scenario:

- I have a user who is admin on 2 different Apple Developer accounts
- I want to log into the Apple Developer portal as the user, and do the following:
- Access the 'Certificates, IDs & Profiles' section, and switch to using the team that I specify
- Access iTunes Connect using the team that I specify

The reason I need this is that I want to automate logging into the Apple Developer portal and perform some maintenance tasks against a specific team, and Fastlane isn't an option right now.

I've tried using the following URL for accessing the 'Certificates, IDs & Profiles' section:

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/?teamId=MY_TEAM_ID

however it doesn't switch to the specified team. I've tried a similar thing for iTunes Connect using the 'switch' parameter on the URL, but that doesn't automatically switch either.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit tricky:

For the account overview page, the different links are working:
https://developer.apple.com/account/#/overview/ABCDEFGHI

But for the actual certificates page, Apple saves the team ID in local storage. If you change it here, it will show/get you the page you want.

[image]

As iTunes Connect is a completely different site, the team selection seems to be based on cookie values, but them look to be encrypted or something.

[image]

It really depends on what kind of "Maintenance tasks" you want to do.